# all ideas how to debug python code

Tags: python, debugging

I need all approaches for debugging python code. 
Now i know this:

- pycharm debugger, ipdb
- logging
- print trace
- raise exception, somewhere in interesting place

Also, i am in interested in approaches , how to debug code inside docker container. Now i know this:

- pycharm remote interpreter
- docker attach + pdb

Thank you, i am interested in your ideas!

Comment: https://github.com/lobocv/crashreporter

Answer (score 3):

You can try [VizTracer](https://github.com/gaogaotiantian/viztracer), which is a profiling/logging tool that will record every entry/exit of your executed function and display those on a timeline. The HTML report looks like this:

[image]

It gives very detailed information of your code execution and you can log arbitrary data while your program is running.